# Cannot import projects eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to import a project into eclipse, but when I click import and select file system, the next button won't work.  I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: Does it give an error message?  If so, what does it say?

Comment: no error message.  I click and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the Release.  I went back to the Stable one.  It seems to work.